# Hibernate lock entire table

Tags: java, hibernate

I don't really want to lock rows, I want to use a table level lock (Postgres' LOCK TABLE MyTable in  ACCESS exclusive MODE`) as a method of synchronizing access around a sequence (only increment it once, when a certain condition holds).  Though the "certain condition" does involve rows, I want to count them, not retrieve them and lock on them.

Does Hibernate support full table locks?

Comment: I suppose an "OK" way to do this would be to change from using a sequence to updating a value in a table (for instance, a table with a single row), then hibernate would lock on that one row (the one we care about incrementing atomically) appropriately. LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible through JPQL/HQL. You will have to execute a native query for doing the locking e.g. `entityManager.createNativeQuery("LOCK TABLE MyTable in ACCESS exclusive MODE").executeUpdate()`